# clojure do or operation on false and nil returns true?

Tags: clojure

i have a clojure code like this

```
(or false nil :a :B)
```

it returns

```
:a
```

how come? false or nil is true? I don't understand it, need help. thanks

Comment: Best accept your answer, so that we can see the question is closed.

Comment: I can accept it only after 2 days. No rush guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will answer my own question.

in clojure, or operator returns first true value.